# Bible and dual meanings of words

Tags: bible

I have a question related to homonyms, I am not sure if one should refer to them as a homonym, however, I will refer to them as such for now.

In the Bible we have a reference to the lion, both Jesus and the devil are referred to using the symbology of the lion, Jesus being the Lion of the tribe of Judah, the devil being a lion seeking whom he may devour.
Some people talk about how lucifer and Jesus are both referred to as the "morningstar", although I understand that this depends on which translation you are reading, as such I do not find this a great example (as with the lion).

Searching the web for examples is not helping me much, articles rather talk about the topic itself, (why both devil and Jesus are referred to as either morningstar or lion).
As such, maybe I am asking the question incorrectly.

As such I now address this question to this platform in the hopes I will get responses.
To make it clear, I am not interested in the why here, I am interested in if there are, and if yes, which words are used that both refer to something evil, and good at the same time.

One more example I will give is the debate on leaven, reading through the scriptures it always refers to something negative, except for one moment where there is a large debate. Did Jesus in His reference to leaven in the context of His parable of the woman and the three measures, denote positive or negative?
Again, I am not interested in the arguments for or against, I am interested in (potential) dual meanings of one word.
Be it lion referring to Jesus (positive) or the devil (negative).
Morningstar (depending on the translation) referring to Jesus or lucifer.
Or the leaven referring to corrupting influences or heavenly influences.

I am going to make it clear I am not interested in the "is or is not true", if you know of a word (for example water, house, gold, or bull) that has potentially 2 opposing meanings (positive and negative) depending on the context, I would like to read about them.
Please provide the word in question with scripture references and the bible version.

Again, I am probably formulating the question wrong, if you know how I should formulate the question, or know about one or more articles written about this topic, I will be happy to receive those.

Comment: This is not clear to me. It seems (to me) that the question is mixing up homonyms (words which have identical letters or sounds, or both, but have  more than one meaning) which occur in both Hebrew and English, with metaphors which _liken_ one thing to another as a literary vehicle. But the question is also broad and imprecise - yes, there are homonyms in the Bible in both the original Hebrew and in the translated English, but what of it ? 'Well' means either a state of wellness or it means a hole in the ground with water at the bottom. That is just a matter of developing language.

Comment: As Nigel implies, homonym is probably the wrong word. A better descriptor is probably metaphor. Since you aren't asking for any exegetical explanations of this kind of usage, this is probably not the right Stack Exchange environment for the question. I would point you to something like the Linguistics stack exchange. I'd point there because this is asking about a linguistic phenomenon that exists across many (maybe even all?) languages.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question isn't about Christianity or biblical doctrine

Comment: Note, I don't follow the "leaven" example. It seems only one concrete example is given, and that without citation. Indeed, the question would generally benefit from citations.

Comment: FWIW, I like this question. But I wish it were just about the Lion of Judah vs St. Peter saying that Satan's like a lion.  And Also proverbs 21:8 (I think).  And that newsboys song...

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few **homonyms**:

- *Light*: It can mean illumination or the opposite of heavy
- *Bite*: to bite is to chomp down on something, or it could denote a small portion of food or even a meal (e.g., Would you like to grab a bite with me?)
- *Bit*: It can be several things: a) the past tense of bite; b) a component of the smallest unit of addressable memory in a given computer (e.g., A byte is a unit of data equal to eight ***bit***s); c) an appliance in the mouth of a horse (e.g., The horse was champing at the bit); or d) a small amount (e.g., I like a bit of spice in my meatballs)
- *Ball*: It can mean a round sphere (e.g., a base-ball or basket-ball), or an evening party or reception that usually involves dancing (e.g., Many [A-listers](https://www.ranker.com/list/celebrities-who-should-be-more-famous/swiperight) were at the ball on Saturday)

Here are a couple of **homophones**:

- *Bite* and *byte*. The former can mean to chomp down on something, and the latter can mean a unit of data
- *Holy* and *wholly*. The former can mean sacred (e.g., The God of the Bible is described as holy), or it could denote completely (e.g., I am wholly committed to the idea)

Here is a **homograph**:

- *Sow* and *sow* can mean sow (pronounced *so–*), as in to scatter seed, or sow (pronounced *sou*, which rhymes with bow-wow), meaning an adult female pig, It can also be a connecting word (e.g., *So*, what are you going to do?) or an activity involving a needle and thread (e.g., Could you sew this rip in my shirt, please?). In the Bible: Jesus describes a "farmer [who] went out in the field to sow his seed" (Matthew 13:3 NIV)and the apostle Peter describes unrighteous people who "follow the corrupt desire of the flesh[c] and despise authority, behaving like sows (“A sow that is washed returns to her wallowing in the mud” (2 Peter 2:2 NIV)

Now that I've thoroughly confused you--and me(!), I think it safe to say that the word *lion* in the Bible is none of the above (i.e., a homonym, homophone, or homograph).

I suggest that the word *lion*, as a descriptor of the character of both Jesus and Satan, is simply a word that describes *specific* and *different* aspects of the metaphor *lion*.

On the one hand, Satan is a lion in the sense that he stealthily and silently stalks his prey with the intent of destroying it (as in "The thief comes only to steal and kill and destroy," John 10:10). On the other hand, Jesus is a lion in the sense that he can be fearsome, inspiring dread in the ungodly who oppose him, or in the sense that he is majestic in his authority, which he displays as the only one who is worthy to open "the scroll and its seven seals" (Revelation 5:5).

In short, a biblical metaphor is flexible in that it can describe someone or something differently in different contexts.